# How to sharpen rnd generator

Tags: c++, qt

I'm making Tetris and have 7 figures.
When I need a new figure I do this in FigureFactory class:

```
srand(time(NULL));
int shape = rand() % 7;
```

Then I get the current and the next figures from FigureFactory:
    the_figure = ff.getFigure();
    next_figure = ff.getFigure();

The result is that the first and the next figure are the same. And the same are figures that I get when quickly push space bar several times.

So, the rnd generator is a bit rough. 
Could you recommend me how to make it more sensitive?

Comment: [`M + rand() / (RAND_MAX / (N - M + 1) + 1)`](http://c-faq.com/lib/randrange.html)

Comment: Can't catch your idea. Could you clarify what M and N mean?

Comment: it a [**Link Read there**](http://c-faq.com/lib/randrange.html) , M and N are numb range

Comment: Can't cope, sorry. I did int shape = rand() / (RAND_MAX / 7 + 1);   And all the figures are the same.

Comment: :( :( , can add some more tags to your question. [tag:c], [tag:c++]

Comment: Have you checked whether `shape` is the same? Maybe there's something wrong with your `getFigure`. Other than that, `srand()` should be called only once, not in front of every `rand()`.

Comment: That's a pretty big "other than" @Zeta.  definitely don't call srand every time.  Just call it once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with `rand()` generator. It is you who explicitly ask it to restart from the same seed value by doing `srand(time(NULL))` before every call to `rand()`. If you do it frequently enough, `time` will simply return the same value and the generator will be reset to the same starting point. No wonder you get the same "random" numbers from `rand()`.

You should not re-seed the generator before every call to `rand()`. It makes no sense. The whole point of `rand()` is to produce a pseudo-random *sequence*. So, let it produce that sequence, don't restart it. If you want to randomize your program's behavior based on current time, re-seed it only once at the start.

You might also re-seed it later, but you should allow some amount of time to pass between the re-seeds. It is better if the amount of time betwee re-seeds is unpredictable, like based on user input delay etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to not call `srand()` every time.  That seems pretty bad.  You should call it very earlier, preferably at some user input (a little better randomness).

Also, using %7 on your rand will give you a bad distribution.

It is much better to get a random number between 0 and 1, then multiply it by your count (7) and take an (int) of it.

```
int shape = (int)((((double)std::rand()) / RAND_MAX) * 7)
```